# What is the difference between the laravel homestead box and the homestead repo?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

From the official docs, "Laravel Homestead is an official, pre-packaged Vagrant box that provides you a wonderful development environment without requiring you to install PHP, HHVM, a web server, and any other server software on your local machine."

I installed vagrant, and downloaded the box, great. But then, later on,
in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead#configuring-homestead), I read I have to install "Homestead" by cloning the repo https://github.com/laravel/homestead/

I find that really confusing, because I thought Homestead was the virtual box I already downloaded. What is the difference between the laravel homestead box and the homestead repo? There are no docs specifically for the github repo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **Homestead Repo**, from *github*, stores your global preferences which are used when running homestead.

The **Homestead Box** is a *virtual machine image* that actually runs the operating system.

**Update**

The recommended local development environment for *Laravel* is **[Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet)**.

> Valet is a Laravel development environment for Mac minimalists. No Vagrant, no /etc/hosts file. You can even share your sites publicly using local tunnels.

There is also a Linux version [available here](https://github.com/cpriego/valet-linux).

**Update *(Aug 06, 2020)***

> Both Valet and Homestead are great choices for configuring your Laravel development environment. Which one you choose will depend on your personal taste and your team's needs.

Comment: The official [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet) state 
**Valet isn't a complete replacement for Vagrant or Homestead, but provides a great alternative if you want flexible basics, prefer extreme speed, or are working on a machine with a limited amount of RAM.**